# How to delete emails older than 2 days through python and IMAP?

Tags: python, gmail, imap

I have a script that would download the google takeout backup export of a particular folder/label, once that part is done, the next step is to execute the delete script.  Because I do the takeout process, it takes 2-3 days to create the back up before I can download it, cause the email backup is quite large. So during that 2-3 days while I wait for the backup to be ready to download, I'll be getting emails and those won't be in the backup export that I've requested.

So I want my script to just delete emails 2-3 days from today's date. Below is my code and I know the section I need to filter/search is in "        typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
"
However, I'm unsure where to exactly filter this and tell it to only flag/select emails that are 2-3 days old and sent to trash. Any help?

```
def deleteEmailIMAP(user, password, IMAP):
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP)
        mail.login(user, password)
        print("Logging into account:", email )
        mail.select("Process") #select folder/label
        print("Process Folder Selected")
        time.sleep(2)
        typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
        print(" Emails from Process Folder sent to Trash")
        for num in data[0].split():
            mail.store(num, '+X-GM-LABELS', r'(\Trash)') #sent to trash and removed from folder
        mail.expunge()
        print("Sent to Trash.")
        print("Emptying Trash & Expunge...")
        mail.select('[Gmail]/Trash')  # select all trash
        mail.store("1:*", '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')  #Flag all Trash as Deleted
        mail.expunge()  # not need if auto-expunge enabled
        print("Done. Closing connection & logging out.")
        time.sleep(2)
        mail.close()
        mail.logout()
        exit()
    deleteEmailIMAP(email, passw, imapserver)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
from imap_tools import MailBox, A

with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'password', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    # delete messages older than 2 days from current (INBOX) folder
    mailbox.delete(mailbox.uids(A(date_lt=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=2))))
```

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Answer (score 1):

This is the key line from your code:

```
typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
```

You can change the `ALL` to e.g. `BEFORE "12-Oct-2020"`, because you don't actually want to search for all mail. See [pages 49-54](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-49) and [page 84](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-84) of the specification for details and other possible search keys.

As an aside, I am quite amazed by how many questions here contain code to search for all mail.

Comment: Especially one’s that don’t even use uid.search.  :)

Comment: Dilshan: Try printing `data` before you change `ALL` to something else. The last number in the `data` array also returned by `mail.select()`. In your case it sort of makes sense, because your question is how to change `ALL` to get the result you want. Lots of people issue that search and think it's fine.